# Redirecting Joomla URLs?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, http-redirect, redirect

There are several forms on my site that still exist in Joomla URLs even though I have permalinks set up for them. For example:

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/component/rsform/?formId=72
http://www.howlatthemoon.com/win-a-party

I tried doing a 301 and it didn't do anything. What can I do? I have Joomla 1.5